# meaning of typical man in this context

Tags: vocabulary, american-english, british-english

> Person 2 - It's late. Our meeting is at 12:20.  
> Person 1 - We can take
> a taxi.  
> Person 2 - ok 
> Person 2 - Did you like my shirt? 
> Person 1 -
> Yeah, it's exactly the same as other one. 
> Person 2 - Same! It's
> completely different! Typical man

Can you please explain the meaning of "Typical man" here?

Comment: What has 'typical man' to do with the dialogue?

Comment: Thank You for the response. Typical man words are in last line.

Comment: OK, in that case it means "You are (like) a typical man (for not noticing how my new shirt is different)". It would have been clearer if you had left out the part about the taxi, and told us that 1 is a man and 2 a woman!

Comment: Source of the quote please!  tell us where you read or heard this.  It is rather odd.  A non-sequitar is when the response has no connection to the prompt.  Here person 1 says "We can take a taxi" and Person2 replies "Did you like my shirt".  That is a non-sequitar Why does P2 ask this?  Person 1's  reply is odd "Yeah (I like it) it is exactly the same"  Being exactly the same is not a good reason to like something, usually.  So.... a little odd.

Answer (score 1):

It's a stereotype that men don't care what they wear, find no value in clothes, are not interested in fashion, are oblivious to how other people dress. If you hold this belief, "a typical man" for you is one showing all/one of the mentioned characteristics.

This behaviour might be irritating to someone who cares about clothes, wear clothes to attract/impress others - the characteristics stereotypically associated with women.

Comment: can you give some other examples "with the help of sentences" to understand it in more details?